# Use pandas in python3 to sum up values from column B per each element from column A

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Can anyone here help me with working on xlsx doc with panda?

Issue is that: I have two columns file. I want to take values from column "A" (these are repetitive) and adequate from column "B" and summ it up.

Example:

```
123abc  100
zxc345  500
123abc 120
zxc345 800
123abc 100
```

I would like to have:

```
123abc 320
zxc345 1300
```

For now my code only sorts me that file:

```
123abc  100
        120
zxc345  500
        800
```

also, please notice, that it does show only once this entry: "123abc 100", despite the fact, that it is repetitive.

Thank you in advance!

Here is code:

```
from sys import argv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import sys

# print("ilosc argumentow",len(sys.argv))

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Give me Excel file: " +  sys.argv[0] + ' niezrealizowane.xlsx')
        quit()
else:
        print("*" * 50)
        print("""Pracuje na: """, sys.argv[1])
        print("*" * 50)



skrypt, ticket = argv

# ZGODNOSCI and NuMERKI are first row in each of affected columns.

data = pd.read_excel(ticket, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "F, H")
data2 = data.groupby(['ZGODNOSCI', 'NuMERKI'])['NuMERKI'].sum()

data2.to_excel('Edzia-test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groupby

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()
```

Example

```
>>> df
        A    B
0  123abc  100
1  zxc345  500
2  123abc  120
3  zxc345  800
4  123abc  100
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()
A
123abc     320
zxc345    1300
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['123abc', 'zxc345', '123abc', 'zxc345', '123abc'], 'col2':[100,500,120,800,100]})
df
    col1  col2
0  123abc   100
1  zxc345   500
2  123abc   120
3  zxc345   800
4  123abc   100

df.groupby(['col1']).agg(col2_sum=('col2', 'sum')).reset_index()
     col1  col2_sum
0  123abc       320
1  zxc345      1300
```